# Windows Form - Control position and size change with screen resolution

Tags: winforms, screen-resolution

I'm writing a Blackjack card game right now, and ran into a bit of a problem.
I have a nice background, with chips on it, a bit further up from the bottom and I want the player to be able to click on certain chips to raise the bet.
The problem is that the transparent boxes I use as buttons have to change if someone plays on a different screen resolution than I. I tried Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height/Width divided by a number, but its still not perfect. Is there a way to precisely set the location of something no matter the scaling or should I just force a certain resolution on the player? If so, how can I set the resolution?

Comment: can you post some code that shows how you are doing it now? Typically you wouldn't force a resolution, but set your window to have a min/max height and width. Then play around with the `Anchor` property of the controls to get them to stay where you want relative to the edge of your window.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I got it :) All I had to do was to add two variables and calculate the screen resolution proportion to 1600×900 I use. Something like this:

```
double ws = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 1600;
double hs = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 900;
```

Then I use SetBounds() to set the bounds of the panel, and in the setbounds I calculate the x,y coordinates using the scale then convert them to int. It is off by a few pixels because of rounding, but acceptable.